# Is there a way to programmatically call from C# statements like CREATE/ALTER DATABASE on SQL Server without creating security issues?

Tags: c#, sql-injection

I have an .NET application which is running the following statement using SqlCommand:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @DB
EXEC(@SQL)
```

The @DB parameter comes from user input, so obviously the application is vulnerable to something like 'X DROP DATABASE Y'. I'm sure there must be an obvious way I'm missing...

Edit: using a parametrized statement cannot work because you cannot use a parameter in CREATE DATABASE (CREATE DATABASE @DB returns a syntax error).

Comment: Why are you creating databases on the fly?  That is a pretty hideous code smell.

Comment: Can you simply validate the user input on the form before sending it to your db? Just make sure there are no spaces.

Comment: @48klocs: to reflect the fact that maybe it's just a bad idea from the beginning, I changed the question title from "how to sanitize this?" to "is it possible to do something like this in a safe way?". Anyway, there's something that I don't quite understand: I think computers are for automating stuff. If someone wants to automate creation of dbs, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should **never, ever** do this from a web app. Ever. Really. I'm serious. With the exception of deployment packages, the only time I've needed to execute a `CREATE DATABASE` is from the query analyzer in SSMS. Additionally, I'm suspicious of any code that would let a user enter a database name, and then go and create it.

Most importantly, **what you've posted is not a "parameterized query." It's concatenated SQL, which is the source of SQL injection vulnerabilities.**. If it were a parameterized query (or a stored proc, but I don't think you can do a `CREATE DATABASE` from a sproc), SQL injection would be a non-issue.

You can either use a real parametrized query ([here is a good tutorial on parametrized queries.](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx)), or sanitize your inputs, but ADO.NET or whatever other db library will reliably handle this for you IF you properly build the command and parameter objects.

Comment: in SQL Server 2008 SP2 you can't use parameters with `create database`: `declare @Test varchar (max) = ''; create database @Test` gives `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2: Incorrect syntax near '@Test'.`

Comment: I agree it's not a good idea to create a db  from user input, but then programming IS about automatizing tasks, isn't it? I'll think about removing the feature, but it's not all up to me. I'll go with sanitizing the input for now, and then maybe later if I have no choice use something like SQL SMO, which probably allows creating dbs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [specify parameters](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7132.asp) - paramaterized queries pretty much eliminate SQL injection attacks (as long as you're not concatenating strings in your receiving stored procedures).

Like I said in my comment, I hope there's an exceptionally good reason for creating databases/tables on the fly where creating rows seems to work for most everyone else.

Comment: It's a ClickOnce application, which uses a (usually) local SQL instance, which is installed with a SQL Express prerrequesite. After installation, the application needs to create the DB and the whole schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use a whitelist approach: allow only letters.